# Can I integrate then differentiate this power series to derive the same result as the binomial series expansion?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I've tried something but I'm not getting the right answer, so I'm wondering why it doesn't work.

I want to taylor expand $\frac1{z^2}$ about some point $a\in\mathbb{C}$. Here's what I did:

\begin{align*}
\int\left(\frac1{z^2}\right)dz = \int\left(z^{-2}\right)dz = \frac1{-1} \frac1z = -\frac1z.
\end{align*}
Now expand about $z=a$,
\begin{align*}
-\frac1z &= -\frac1{a+z-a} = -\frac1{a\left(1+\frac{z-a}a\right)} = -\frac1a\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-\frac{z-a}{a}\right)^n,\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{a^{n+1}}(z-a)^n.\\
\left(-\frac1z\right)' &= \frac1{z^2} = \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{a^{n+1}}(z-a)^n\right)' = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{n}{a^{n+1}}(z-a)^{n-1}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{n}{a^2}\left(\frac{z-a}{a}\right)^{n-1}.
\end{align*}
The binomial series, on the other hand, tells me
\begin{align*}
(1+x)^\alpha = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}n x^n \Rightarrow \left[1+\left(\frac{z-a}a\right)\right]^{-2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-2}{n} \left(\frac{z-a}a\right)^n,
\end{align*}
Am I doing something wrong, or is there an identity I'm not seeing?

Comment: Isnt the sum in $(1+x)^\alpha = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}n x^n$just go from 0 to $\alpha$?

Comment: @PnDChameleon Wikipedia claims it isn't: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Comment: yeah, sorry, thats right for $|\alpha|<1$

Comment: In your opinion, what is $\binom{-2}{n}$?

Comment: @GEdgar Good question....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

By definition, we have

$$\binom{-2}{n}=\frac{(-2)(-3)(-4)\cdots (-n-1)}{(+2)(+3)(+4)\cdots \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(n)}=(-1)^n(n+1)$$

---

**SPOLIER ALERT** Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solution

> We have \begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{n}{a^2}\left(\frac{z-1}{a}\right)^{n-1}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n}\frac{n+1}{a^2}\left(\frac{z-1}{a}\right)^{n}\\\\&=\frac{1}{a^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-2}{n}\left(\frac{z-1}{a}\right)^{n}\end{align}

Comment: In regard to the spoiler: Why not set $m\equiv n-1$ and observe that the $m=-1$ solution doesn't contribute tot the sum?

Comment: Or was that the same as what you meant in a more abstract notation...?

Comment: It was the same.  Note the equality of the series.  On the LHS, the term at $n=0$ doesn't contribute.  So, one can start at $n=1$ on the LHS.  Does that make sense now?